# How can I return a boolean if the constructor keeps giving the error that the method is undefined for a specified Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

The program is said to return whether the `Venue` is available on a specified date; whilst the availability is made by cycling through the list of approved events to see if the date on any event matches the date the argument gives.

I have this code:

```
private ArrayList<Event> approvedEvents=new ArrayList<Event>();

public boolean available(Date date) { //need to finish and fix this code
     
    for (int x=0; x <= approvedEvents.size(); x++) {
        
        if(approvedEvents.getDate(x) == date) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

However the error be shown is that:

```
getDate(int) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Event>.
```

Comment: The error is correct; an `ArrayList` does not have a method named `getDate`. There is not much else to say.

Comment: `approvedEvents.get(x).getDate()`

Comment: And you most likely do not want to compare that result with `==` but with `equals` or allow for some difference, or only extract the hour or day or ...

Comment: Your `return` statement is in the wrong place.  As it is, you're always going to return from your function after one iteration through your `for` loop.  Move `return false` outside your `for` loop.

Comment: arrayList doesnt have the getDate method. maybe you need to try approvedEvents.get(x).getDate.equals(date)

Comment: `approvedEvents.stream().map(Event::getDate).anyMatch(date::equals)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problems are:

1. You are calling `getDate()` on the list of events instead of on a particular event.
2. You should use `equals()` to compare dates, not `==`
3. Your return statement is in the wrong place.

Here's an alternative version of your code that fixes these problems and also shows you how to more directly iterate over your list of events:

```
private ArrayList<Event> approvedEvents=new ArrayList<Event>();

public boolean available(Date date) { //need to finish and fix this code
    for (Event event: approvedEvents) {
        if (event.getDate().equals(date)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your title, you refer to a "constructor".  I don't know what you mean by that.  There's nothing about your question that involves a constructor.  You aren't creating any objects, so no constructor is being called by this code, and neither does it define a constructor.

Another issue you may have is that you might be comparing two dates that will never be the same because they differ in the time of day.  If all you want is to test if an event is on a particular day, you could define and call this function instead of calling `Date.equals()`:

```
public static boolean isSameDay(Date date1, Date date2) {
    Instant instant1 = date1.toInstant()
      .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    Instant instant2 = date2.toInstant()
      .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    return instant1.equals(instant2);
}
```

To use this function, you'd do:

```
if(isSameDay(approvedEvents.getDate(x), date)) {
```

Note: The function above was taken from [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-two-dates-on-same-day).